# JQuery with file upload works in development but not production

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to implement a multi-file upload via jquery and I have tried it with JQuery File Upload and Dropzone. Both work fine in development but fail in production for some reason.

Here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).on("ready page:load", function() {

// Drop Zone
if($('#dropzone').length) {
    $("#dropzone").dropzone({
    maxFilesize: 1.5,
    paramName: "picture[image]",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*,.psd'
});}

});
```

Here is the form where I load the images:

```
<%= form_for(Picture.new, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone", :id=>"dropzone" }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field(:activity_id, :value => @activity.id) %>
<% end %>
```

This works perfectly fine in development but in production, I get the following error:

[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#dropzone").dropzone

I get a similar error message with JQuery file upload.

Can someone help with this? I have also precompiled the assets.

Comment: Sounds like your Javascript assets are not being loaded in production. Can you give us any info on this - which environment are you using (`Heroku`?) Have you precompiled your assets?

Comment: Yes, I am using Heroku and I have precompiled my assets